# Compilation error (combine class + hyperref package): TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

Tags: hyperref, combine

I would like to create a "journal" with several papers, using the `combine` class.

In the example below, there are one master file and two articles.

Master file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{combine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopenlevel=\maxdimen, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=red, implicit=false,dvipdfm]{hyperref}

\title{Journal of }
\author{A. N. Editor}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\begin{papers}

\makeatletter
\let\@begindocumenthook\relax
\makeatother

\coltoctitle{An article}
\coltocauthor{A.~N.~Author}
\label{art1}
\import{art1}
\clearpage

\coltoctitle{Another article}
\coltocauthor{A.~N.~Other}
\label{art2}
\import{art2}
\clearpage

\end{papers}

\end{document}
```

First article:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopenlevel=\maxdimen, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=red, implicit=false, dvipdfm]{hyperref}

\title{An article}
\author{A.~N.~Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Second article:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopenlevel=\maxdimen, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=red, implicit=false, dvipdfm]{hyperref}

\title{Another article}
\author{A.~N.~Other}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

The compilation is stopped and an error message is given:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\clearpage ...Call@BeforeClearDocument \clearpage

\Call@AfterLastShipout
l.17 \end{document}

If you really absolutely need more capacity, you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Note: If the `hyperref` package is not activated in the preamble of the master file, the entire document is correctly created.

I would like to get a document with hyperlinks (e.g. figures) and bookmarks. Thus, I would like to use `hyperref`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: \clearpage is being defined to expand to a definition that includes \clearpage so you get into an infinite loop didn't spot where the culprit was yet but this may help you narrow it down

Comment: If I uncomment the redefinition of `\@begindocumenthook`, it hangs at `\captions@French ->\captions@French`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the endless loop in package [`atveryend 2012/10/15 v1.9`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71873949/tex/atveryend-1.9.pdf).
Also [`hobsub 2012/10/15 v1.15`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71873949/tex/hobsub-1.15.pdf) needs to be updated, because it contains `atveryend`.
The PDF files contain the DTX sources as file attachments. The packages are unpacked by running the DTX files through `tex` (*not* `latex`). The new versions will be part of the next bundle update at a later time.

But the class `combine` will not work well with `hyperref`, because internals are overwritten, that are redefined by `hyperref` (\label, \ref, \@setref, …).

BTW,

```
\makeatletter
\let\@begindocumenthook\relax
\makeatother
```

can be abbreviated by

```
\emptyAtBeginDocument
```